Can I use my ubuntu pro 24.04 subscription on 22.04?
I recently purchased an Ubuntu Pro subscription for version 24.04, and I am currently running Ubuntu 22.04 on some of my machines. I would like to know if I can use my 24.04 subscription to enable Ubuntu Pro features on my 22.04 installations. Thank you.

I’m voting to close this question because this is a commercial question to be answered by Canonical support.
